# VSTO Outlook: How to cancel Outlook.MailItem_PropertyChanged from within the event

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

Is there any way I can stop propagating the event MailItem_PropertyChanged from within the handler?

Something  like e.Cancel = True is not possible within MailItem_PropertyChanged. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

No, the Outlook object model doesn't provide such events. The best what you could do is to set the property to the required value and skip the next event for that.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. If you are trying to hide the event from other subscribers, there is no predetermined order in which the subscribes are notified. And if it is for your own code, your are free to ignore the notification.